# How can I generate new paths on a website

Tags: web-applications, web-deployment

For every user, I want to generate a unique sharable link, a custom path like 'abc.com/Adf3f34fsdSD'. How can I go about this?

My idea is as so

  1. When a user goes on the site, assign a custom path
  2. Store the path in a db along with some information
  3. When another person navigates to the path, look the path up in the db, and display the information

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't have any code at the moment, I'm trying to research the right approach as I am very new to web development. The most Ive done is make a couple of personal websites.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Your approach sounds reasonable and is probably how I would go about it. There would be no single "right approach" to creating identifiers so get stuck in and play around with it.